# javascript transformToDocument XSLT not expected output

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to execute xsl transformation directly by the browser (Chrome) by using the code below.

The objective is to use the XML as a database that could be used to extract information by using xsl (and a good html output) but something seems to be wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css"/>
        <script>
    
            function displayResult()
            {
                var text_xml = "<div id='example'><div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div><div>5</div><div>6</div><div>7</div><div>8</div><div>9</div><div>VALOR</div></div>";
                parser = new DOMParser();
                xml = parser.parseFromString(text_xml,"text/xml");
                var text_xls="<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'><xsl:template match='/'><xsl:for-each select='(./div/div[(. = 'VALOR')])'><div><xsl:value-of select='.'/></div></xsl:for-each></xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>";
                parser2 = new DOMParser();
                xlsDoc = parser2.parseFromString(text_xls,"text/xml"); 
                {
                    xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
                    xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xlsDoc);
                    xml = xsltProcessor.transformToDocument(xml, document);
      
                }
                xml = parser.parseFromString(text_xml,"text/xml");
                S3L = xml;
 
document.getElementById("CR_tab").innerHTML=S3L.documentElement.outerHTML;
           }
       </script>
       </head>
       <body onload="displayResult()">
    
           <div id="CR_id" class="w3-container my_tab">
               <h2>Result</h2>
               <div id="CR_tab">
     
               </div>
           </div>
    
    
       </body>
</html>
```

The code runs ok, but the result is not coming out as expected:
The expected result:

```
    Result
    1

The result I'm getting:

    Result
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9
    VALOR
```

I have tested with some xsl processors and the result is fine but with the Chrome processor not

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Why that `xml = parser.parseFromString(text_xml,"text/xml");` after the `transformToDocument` call? And why don't you use `transformToFragment` if the aim is to insert HTML into an existing document.

Comment: I don't see how that XSLT would give the result you say you get but using `<xsl:for-each select='(./div/div[(. = 'VALOR')])'>` where you use a single quote as the attribute value delimiter of the `select` as well as inside of the attribute value as an XPath string delimiter should fail with an XML parse error.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments, you have an error with your brackets. The `xsl:for-each` string should not be `<xsl:for-each select='(./div/div[(. = 'VALOR')])'>`, but rather

```
<xsl:for-each select='(./div/div[(. = "VALOR")])'>
```

In XSLT (or XPath), the string delimiters have to alternated: `'`,`"`,`'` ... `'`,`"`,`'`.

After applying this change, your still have the problem that your expression didn't give you what you want as an output.

The most simple approach would be the following XSLT string:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>
    <xsl:template match='/'>
        Result:
        <xsl:value-of select='div/div[1]'/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Its output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

        Result:
        1
```

Maybe this is really what you want. But then, I do not see the relevance of the string `VALOR` in your code...

Comment: I have replaced the xslt by: `<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>
 <xsl:template match='/'>
  <div>
   <xsl:value-of select='div/div[1]'/>
  </div>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>` but the render is the same output.

Comment: But using xmlspy the render is : ´<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><div>1</div>´

Comment: Here is the new var replaced and by using transformToFragment as well, 'var text_xls="<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'><xsl:template match='/'><div><xsl:value-of select='div/div[1]'/></div></xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>";'

Comment: @ggdepaz, do you know that StackOverflow, for HTML and JavaScript, allows you to insert an executable code sample in your question? Perhaps do that to allow others to easily reproduce the result you say you get.

Answer (score 0):

The following code JavaScript code, using the XSLT from the other answer, seems to work in Chrome, giving solely the value `1`:

```js
var text_xml = "<div id='example'><div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div><div>5</div><div>6</div><div>7</div><div>8</div><div>9</div><div>VALOR</div></div>";
 
 const xsl = `<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>
    <xsl:template match='/'>
        Result:
        <xsl:value-of select='div/div[1]'/>
    <\/xsl:template>
<\/xsl:stylesheet>`;

const domParser = new DOMParser();

const doc = domParser.parseFromString(text_xml, 'application/xml');

const xsltDoc = domParser.parseFromString(xsl, 'application/xml');

const processor = new XSLTProcessor();
processor.importStylesheet(xsltDoc);

const resultFrag = processor.transformToFragment(doc, document);

console.log(resultFrag);

document.querySelector('#output').appendChild(resultFrag);
```

```html
<h1>Test</h1>
<div id=output></div>
```

Comment: It works thank you....with some small mods to my code, I will investigate why the other is not working, strange id xsl definition was wrong It shouldn't parse